# Hamiltonian Graphs and connected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Prove or disprove: There exists an integer k such that every k-connected graph is hamiltonian.

Comment: any thoughts of yours on this topic?

Comment: It seems to be false but I am having difficulty finding a counter example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempting to do these questions serve as good practice if you are doing a graph theory course.

An idea, I think look at $M_{2k+1}$ for all $k \geq 3$.

Comment: If you take k=3 then according to their definition of M_2k+1 you get a wheel with 2k = 6 spokes and deleting k=3 mutually nonadjacent vertices gives you a graph which is no longer k-connected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Look at $M_{7}$, we have $7$ points, $6$ in a circle. a - b - c - d - e - f - a, where a,c,e are connected to the central point $p$.
(we remove $3$ edges, not three vertices).

Comment: Okay I see, thanks.

Comment: @Alex: Can you point to a general description of (or just a googlable name for) $M_{2k+1}$? I can't find that notation in Wikipedia's list of parametic families of graphs.

Comment: Sure, $M_{2k+1}$ is the graph that is obtained from a wheel on $2k$ spokes by deleting a set of $k$ spokes incident to $k$ mutually nonadjacent points. This definition can be found in 'Graph Theory' by F.Harary.

Comment: @Alex: That's not $k$-connected for $k\ge 3$. In fact it's not ever $3$-connected. In your $M_7$ example, removing $a$ and $c$ will cause $b$ to fall away from the rest of the graph.